# How to fetch data with slot in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a code block like this.

```
<template slot="name" slot-scope="row">{{row.value.first}} {{row.value.last}}</template>
```

Also I have a header.

```
    { isActive: true, age: 38, name: { first: 'Jami', last: 'Carney' } },
    { isActive: false, age: 27, name: { first: 'Essie', last: 'Dunlap' } },
    { isActive: true, age: 40, name: { first: 'Thor', last: 'Macdonald' } },
```

This code is running clearly but I want to show data from my API. Which terms do I need to know? I used Axios before in React. Where can I define Axios method? Do I need to change the template slot instead of :v-slot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can make API calls directly from inside the component code, it does not mean that you should. It's better to decouple API calls into a separate module.
Here's a good way to do it which properly follows Separation of Concern (SoC) principle:

1. Create a directory `services` under `src` if it's not already there.
2. Under `services`, create new file named `api.service.js`.

api.service.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api'; // Change this according to your setup

export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
});
```

3. Create another file `peopleData.service.js`

```js
import api from './api.service';
import handleError from './errorHandler.service'; // all the error handling code will be in this file, you can replace it with console.log statement for now.

export default {
    fetchPeopleData() {
        return api.get('/people')
            .catch((err) => handleError(err));
    },

    // All other API calls related to your people's (users'/customers'/whatever is appropriate in your case) data should be added here.
    addPerson(data) {
        return api.post('/people', data)
            .catch((err) => handleError(err));
    },
}
```

Now you can import this service into your component and call the function.

```html
<template>
... Template code
</template>

<script>
import peopleDataService from '@/services/peopleData.service';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        peopleDataService.fetchPeopleData().then((res) => {
            if (res && res.status == 200) {
                this.rows = res.data;
            }
        });
    },
}
</script>
```

You haven't given us any idea about your current setup. If you're using Vue-Router, it's better to fetch data in navigation guards, especially if your component is relying on the data: [Data Fetching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html)

Simply shift the code from mounted() into a navigation guard. `this` may not be available, so you will have to use `next` callback to set `rows` array, it's explained in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axios in methods or mounted.

```
mounted(){
    this.loading = true;
    axios
    .get(`${this.backendURL}/api/v1/pages/layouts` , authHeader())
    .then(response => (this.layouts = response.data.data))
    .catch(handleAxiosError);
}

methods: {
      /**
        * Search the table data with search input
        */
      uncheckSelectAll(){
        this.selectedAll = false
      },
      onFiltered(filteredItems) {
          // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
          this.totalRows = filteredItems.length;
          this.currentPage = 1;
      },
      handlePageChange(value) {
          this.currentPage = value;
          axios
          .get(`${this.backendURL}/api/v1/pages?per_page=${this.perPage}&page=${this.currentPage}` , authHeader())
          .then(response => (this.pagesData = convert(response.data.data),
                             this.pagesDataLength = response.data.pagination.total));
        },
      handlePerPageChange(value) {
        this.perPage = value;
        this.currentPage = 1;
        axios
        .get(`${this.backendURL}/api/v1/pages?per_page=${this.perPage}&page=${this.currentPage}` , authHeader())
        .then(response => (this.pagesData = convert(response.data.data),
                           this.pagesDataLength = response.data.pagination.total));
      },
      deletePage(){
        this.loading = true
        this.$bvModal.hide("modal-delete-page");
        window.console.log(this.pageIdentity);
        if (!roleService.hasDeletePermission(this.pageIdentity)){
          return;
        }
        axios
        .delete(`${this.backendURL}/api/v1/pages/${this.page.id}` , authHeader())
        .then(response => (
          this.data = response.data.data.id,
          axios
          .get(`${this.backendURL}/api/v1/pages?per_page=${this.perPage}&page=${this.currentPage}` , authHeader())
          .then(response => (this.pagesData = convert(response.data.data),
                             this.pagesDataLength = 

    response.data.pagination.total)),
              alertBox(`Page deleted succesfully!`, true)
              ))
            .catch(handleAxiosError)
            .finally(() => {
                this.loading =  false
            });
          }
```

Comment: Only mounted method is enough ? After that <template slot="data" slot-scope="row">{{response.data.data.first}} {{row.value.last}}</template> like tihs ?